# I am trying to add the 6th animation but I don't know why it's doesn't show

Tags: html, css

I copied this code from codepen and there is only 5 text looping I want to add the 6th  to show but when i copy the same style with new class name i.e "w6" and the new animation with "w6anim" it doesn't load the 6th waqas. Kindly help!

I tried to change @keyframe values but still, it doesn't work.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: system;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local(".SFNSText-Light"), local(".HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Light"), local(".LucidaGrandeUI"), local("Ubuntu Light"), local("Segoe UI Light"), local("Roboto-Light"), local("DroidSans"), local("Tahoma");
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: "system";
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
}

.word {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
}

.w1 {
  animation: w1anim 20s infinite;
}

.w2 {
  animation: w2anim 20s infinite;
}

.w3 {
  animation: w3anim 20s infinite;
}

.w4 {
  animation: w4anim 20s infinite;
}

.w5 {
  animation: w5anim 20s infinite;
}

.w6 {
  animation: w6anim 20s infinite;
  color: red;
}

@keyframes w1anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes w2anim {
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes w3anim {
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes w4anim {
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes w5anim {
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes w6anim {
  50% {
    opacity: 0 !important;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="word w1">LOREM</div>
  <div class="word w2">IPSUM</div>
  <div class="word w3">CARPE</div>
  <div class="word w4">DIEM</div>
  <div class="word w5">AVENO</div>
  <div class="word w6">waqas</div>
</div>
```

link to the codepen https://codepen.io/waqasahmad9961/pen/bGbxpNr

Comment: remove !important, they aren't valid inside keyframes

Comment: I tried what @TemaniAfif says and he/she is right.

Answer (score 0):

Remote !important and simply copy 1:1 in future cases.. never change a running system

Answer (score -1):

```js
@keyframes w6anim {
  50% {
    opacity: 0 !important;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Remove ->  !important